# Silicone with good thermal conductivity

Tags: thermodynamics, materials, temperature

I am looking for a material with the same properties of silicone (flexible, easy to manipulate, soft, etc.) but **without being a thermal isolate**.

I need this material to do the junction between a temperature sensor and the human skin (this is why I need it to be soft).

So far I've used the [ELASTOSIL® E43](https://www.wacker.com/cms/en/products/product/product.jsp?product=9037) but without good results.

Comment: For microelectronic packaging people use 'loaded' epoxies to increase thermal conductivity. Silver is a common loading and can be used if you want conductivity (ground contact). If an insulating bond is desired, the often use alumina powder. The trick is to find a balance of loading and other properties of interest.

Comment: Beryllium oxide is used to improve the thermal conductivity of silicone pastes used on heat sinks...  but BeO is toxic. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium_oxide